Pipeline Stage to Rollback to Previous successful deployment if pipeline fails at the time of deployment
Hi need help from community i stuck in my project were i want to rollback my deployment if my build get fails. If my deployment get fails i want automatically move to previous successful deployment in Jenkins pipeline.
can anyone have any idea regrading this ?
I tried but unable to rollback to previous successful deployment.

Show what you have tried
